# ODBC Windows Server 2003 from Windows Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, odbc

We need to make SQL selection over ODBC from a Windows 2003 server to a Windows 2012 server (I know 2003 is risk and unsupported)

I have installed the ODBC native SQL driver from Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 SP2 on the windows 2003 server. Configure and test the connection work.

In PHP I use:

```
$dsn = "stackoverflowdsn";
$user = "stackoverflow";
$pwd = "stackoverflow"; 

if (!$conn = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $pwd))
{
   echo "ODBC-Connection failed";

   exit;
} 
else {
         if ($conn) {
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM [DBNAME].[dbo].[Status];";
         $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
         while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
             $name = odbc_result($rs,"Name");
             echo "name : $name <br>";
         }
     }
}   
?>
```

The number of columns is correct but the result is a lot of trash:

```
name :
name : ãG
name : ãG
name : ãG
name : ãG
G
name : ãG
name : ãG
name : ãG
G¨
name : ãG
name : ãG
```

The chars changes sometimes

I set the compatibility of the 2012 Servers Database to SQL Server 2008 (100).

Can anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The databasetype for string was set from the ef core to nvarchar, with varchar it works